# Unknown "google is not defined" Google Maps integration in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, angular-components

Here's the context of the problem I am trying to solve: I am trying to program a google map integration with a heat map overlay. It currently should be a visible map centered in San Francisco (later I will add a button to overlay the heat map and toggle the heat map). Yet, I keep getting this error in my console stating:

ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at HeatMapComponent.push../src/app/heat/heat-map/heat-map.component.ts.HeatMapComponent.ngOnInit

Here is the code for my angular component:

heat-map.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {   } from '@types/googlemaps';



@Component({
selector: 'app-heat-map',
templateUrl: './heat-map.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./heat-map.component.css']
})
export class HeatMapComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("gmap") gmapElement: any;

  public heatmapData: Array<google.maps.LatLng>;
  public verb: google.maps.LatLng;
  public map: google.maps.Map;

  public heatmap: google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer;
  public heatMapON: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.heatmapData = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.2, -122.7),
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.2, -122.5),
     ];

     this.cool = new google.maps.LatLng(37.2, -122.04);

     var mapProp = { center: this.cool, zoom: 3, mapTypeId: 
                 google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE };

     this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);

     this.heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                    data: this.heatmapData
     });

     this.heatMapON = false;
     }

  toggleHeatMap(event){
     console.log("Heat Map is now overlayed on google Map", event)
     this.heatMapON = !this.heatMapON
     if (this.heatMapON) {
        this.heatmap.setMap(this.map);
     }
     else {
        this.heatmap.setMap(null)
     }
  }
}
```

heat-map.component.css

```
 #gmap {
     height: 400px;
     width: 100%;
 }
```

heat-map.component.html

```
 <div #gmap></div>
 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&libraries=visualization">
 </script>
```

And nothing of this component is displayed on my localhost.

Comment: I suspect the Google Maps JavaScript API is not loaded yet when you try to call it inside ngOnInit(). Note that you are loading API asynchronously, in this case you should provide a callback function that will be executed once the API is completely loaded. Maybe you can use setTimeout() as a workaround to initialize  map with a slight delay in ngOnInit().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the script for maps is being called within the heat-map.component.html

It should be referenced in the index.html of your project in `<head>` and furthermore, I believe the async and defer attributes added on the script tag are causing it not to load in sequence, and therefore is non-existent when heat-map.component is calling it.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Gmaps</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&libraries=visualization"></script>
</head>
```

Info on [defer/async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes)

Comment: I implemented this fix and it now compiles with 0 errors, yet the map still isn't showing. Any ideas?

Comment: use a class on your div and in css, make sure the height and width on the parent are setting properly, only snag I ran into.  @Enesxg

Comment: Yeah, using a # in the html creates a reference variable, and in your css you are attempting to set the styling to the id, so it isn't applying.  What you can do is either set div like `<div id="gmap" #gmap></div>` or (I would use this) `<div class="map-container" #gmap></div>`  and change your css selector to `.map-container {height: 400px; width: 100%;}`